# Linq query on the same table with difference between rows

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I've been trying to develop a linq query that returns results from the same table.

```
ORDERS

YEAR        NumberOfOrders
--------------------------
2009            150

2010            195

2011            180

2012            110
```

The query must returns the diffrence between the current and the last year (2012 and 2011) like follows :

Result:

```
YEAR     NumberofOrders      DIFFERENCE
---------------------------------------
2012         110                -70
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: are you on a database engine that supports LEAD and LAG functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it by myself

```
var query = (from o1 in context.orders
             where o1.year == lastyear
             from o2 in context.orders
             where o2.year == currentyear
             select new
             {
                difference = o2.numberOfOrders - o1.numberOfOrders,
                numberOfOrders =  o2.numberOfOrders,
                year = o2.year                    
             });
```

Thanks,